# Javascript how to redirect to another website and send the JWT as bearer token as well

Tags: javascript, ajax, jwt, fetch-api

I need to redirect to another website and send the JWT as a bearer token as well.

Can I use fetch to do it?

Something like this:

```
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    document.getElementById('Aother-Website-Link').addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      fetch('Another-Website-Link',
        {
        mode: "cors",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`
        }
      })
        .then(() => {
          window.location.href = 'Another-Website-Link';
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Does it work?

Comment: No, fetch cannot redirect the current page. The only way is `window.location` but that cannot set any headers. It's basically the same as clicking on a link.

Comment: @derpirscher then what is the solution for redirecting to another website and sending the JWT as a bearer token as well?

Comment: You need some other way to send the token. If you redirect the user the only real option you have is the URI, but that's not secure. OAuth2 has a good flow for dealing with this. (authorization_code + PKCE). Instead of reinventing your own auth, you might be better to use something built by experts.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. First, cookies cannot be transfered nor set across different domains, cookies can only be set if the server is sitting on the same domain or a subdomain.

If your website is `website1.com` and you make a fetch request to `backend2.com`, `backend2.com` cannot set any cookies for your website. If you wanted to set cookies on your website, your website should either make a fetch request to the same domain (`website1.com/api/something`) or a subdomain like `api.website1.com`.

With this in mind, no, you cannot redirect and transfer cookies to another website.

If you have access to the site there might be a solution. You can set up a custom route on the site you want to redirect to, call it something like `/redirectCallback` or something like that, and then you can redirect the user and either pass in your cookies via an url query (`/redirect callback?cookie1Val=...`) so that the website you want to redirect to can parse those values, send them to their server and then their server can set the same cookies, or, if you want more security and you also happen to have a database set up, you can create a temporary `switchSession` with and `id` and `cookieValue` fields on your server right before you redirect and send it's id via url query (`/redirectCallback?redirectSessionId=...`) and then the website can again parse it, send it to their server, their server will parse the data on your database then delete the `redirectSession` and send your cookies up to the client again (You can implement signing/veryfing if you want even more security).

I hope it helped!

Edit: spelling.